# Closest iOS 5 compatible equivalent of SLComposeViewController?

Tags: facebook, ios5, ios6, slcomposeviewcontroller

In am using [SLComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for posting on Facebook with iOS 6. In an effort to have a consistent user experience and save development time, are there any existing code snippets or libraries with similar behavior and feel to SLComposeViewController that work in iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DETweetComposeViewController which looks similar to SLComposerViewController and compatible for ios 6.
check this http://www.developers-life.com/facebook-compose-view.html
this may help you.

Comment: What does the link provide?  What happens if the link changes? This answer will be rendered useless.